# Drupal 7 Apache Solr search missing fields in Facets config overlay

Tags: solr, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal, apachesolr and facetapi. I have a default server defined in my search environment; the Facets configuration doesn't list some of my article fields (the article entity type is configured for indexing). I created a second environment and this lists the same limited facets as the default environment. Any suggestions on how I can get all the article fields listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields Apache solr includes in its facets configuration page should be only fields that are **select-type fields or taxonomy terms**, or something similar.

If you have a field that's just a regular 'Text' or 'Integer' or 'Link' field, it won't appear in that facets configuration page, because those type of fields don't work well as facets.

If you want a field you have to be used as a facet, make sure you make its type be something that can be selected from a list.  Does that make sense?  Was that the problem in your case?

Comment: Doh! (slaps forehead) It does make sense -- although I guess I expected Solr to perform some blackbox magic and spit out some reasonable facets on other elements. Sorry for the delayed answer CHECK, I missed the notification...THANKS Boriana!